# SSD installed but system reserved drive is visible, how to fix?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I've just installed an SSD as primary boot drive. During install, a system reserved partition was allocated (not very big) around 100MB. Problem is the drive is visible in explorer and its assigned to D:

Anyone else had this problem, and is there a way to somehow hide that drive from explorer, and also get back the drive letter assignment?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Press Start.
2. Type in **Computer Management** and press enter.
3. From the options in the left column, click on **Disk Management**.
4. In the bottom half of your screen, you'll see rectangles representing each partition in your computer. Right-click on the 100MB partition that's labeled "System Reserved" and select **Change Drive Letter and Paths**
5. Make sure **D:** is highlighted, then click **Remove**.

Comment: What a really solid answer!!!! Thanks a million I would have never have thought of this... and it worked like a charm!!!

Answer (score 1):

What version of Windows are you running?  If you open up `Disk Management` can you select the drive, select `Change drive letter and path` and then `Remove` the drive letter?